# using timeago with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, timeago

Anyone try this yet?  I am having a tough time getting it to work.

I tried initializing it in the head of my template using both(one or the other) the following:

```
<script>
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
   jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
</script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
</script>
```

Then in the content section, I try implementing it with :

`<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>`

Just as the timeago documentation suggests.

Though I only see `July 17, 2008` and no dynamic time changes.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, as you can see in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/KXHBj/

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(".timeago").timeago();
});
```